# JMETER 4. 0 | JMeter distributed load testing | jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

I have set up a login->logout script using JMeter and performing load testing using a distributed machine. The username is dynamically populated in login using the user.CSV list while the password for the login is fixed and hardcoded in the login request.

- Master(My own machine)
- 2 slaves machines
- Thread: jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group
- Users: 10
- Hold Load: 120

When executing the script using NON-GUI mode with a command:

jmeter -n -t "c:\Login and Logout.jmx" -R slaveip1, slaveip2.

The summary report is generated is as below:

Summariser: summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)

Can someone help me out to find out why the summary report is not getting populated?

**Note**: When the script is executed for a single user then the summary report is getting populated. Here in the login request both username and password are hardcoded and username not coming for CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure to copy the CSV file to the slave machines
2. Make sure to install [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) plugin to all the slave machines (this applies to any other plugins used in your test as well)
3. If anything goes wrong make sure to check *jmeter.log* on master and `jmeter-server.log` file on slaves - in case of error JMeter should report the cause via the log file.
4. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever version is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.